# Streaming Live Webcams

Tags: video-streaming, streaming, webcam, live-streaming

Building a website where members can stream their webcams to my server so that other members can view the live feeds that are currently streaming.

Sort of like: http://chatroulette.com

> **How do I take a member's webcam, push the feed to the server, and then allow others to view the feeds in real-time?**

The website is web-based, written in PHP with a MySQL database - but I'm willing to add Javascript, jQuery, Flash, or whatever is needed to make this work.

I know this is broad but really need some guidance here!

Comment: Sorry, but this is way too broad question to answer. You don't even mention what programming language you're talking about (I assume this is a web app)?

Comment: This is way too general as a question. Be more specific. What are you trying to build, a website? an desktop application? mobile? what are your specs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to solve 3 three problems.

1. Stream your member’s webcam to your server.
   I would start with RTSP/RTP as protocol and do H.264/AAC for compression of the AV streams.
   You need a software that compresses the WEB cam’s output – start with ffmpeg (build it with x264 and libfaac included) and live555 (http://www.live555.com/liveMedia/) for the RTSP/RTP server.
   You could also try using libVLC that will give you RTSP/RTP stream with compression based.
   For a prototype you can use the VLC player and have it stream the web cam for you: http://geraldnaveen.blogspot.com/2009/04/streaming-webcam-using-vlc.html
2. Your server has to receive the RTSP/RTP streams
   I would use live555 again but now you have to receive RTP – hence you have to use the RTSP client. You can prototype with http://www.live555.com/openRTSP/ and testRTSPClient is a good starting point.
3. Now your server has to re-stream the various webcams in a format that browsers understand – ideally without a plug-in or flash. I’d try HTTP live streaming. Check http://www.longtailvideo.com/html5/hls/. Ultimately your server has to “transmux” the incoming streams to MP4 or HLS and may be transcode to WeM for Chrome.

Comment: How would the browser be able to RTP to your website in the first place? Do you need Flash/Java?

Comment: Your browser would connect to the server (3.) and the server should provide a supported stream. For example HLS for Safari. Other browsers may need a plug-in.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Flash or WebRTC (only on newer browsers). Something like [TokBox](http://www.tokbox.com/opentok) or [Vline](https://vline.com/) will give you a simple way of allowing the clients to talk peer-to-peer.